# re-count numbers in string in array of objects of specific string when an object is deleted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an issue of re counting the numbers in strings. I am trying to re calculate title numbers based on it's kindof type. e.g. When I delete `Oranges 2` from [Oranges 1, Oranges 2, Oranges 3], it should become [Oranges 1, Oranges 2] i.e. I wanted to re count the numbers irrespective of it's previous number. One can delete any i.e. 1 or 5 or last e.g. say 10

```
const req = [
    {id: 'z1', title:"Oranges 1"},
    {id: 'y1', title:"Apples 1"},
    // Oranges 2 deleted
    {id: 'a1', title: "Oranges 3"},
    {id: 'b1', title: "Apples 2"},
    // Apples 3 deleted
    {id: 'a3', title: "Apples 4"},
    {id: 'b2', title: "Oranges 4"},
    {id: 'b6', title: "Apples 5"},
    {id: 'c3', title: "Oranges 5"},
    {id: 'x1', title: "Apples 6"},
];

const titlesWithNoDigits = req.map(tab => {
  return { ...tab, title: (tab?.title || '').replace(/[0-9]/g, '').trim() };
});

const res = titlesWithNoDigits.reduce((obj, next) => {
        const updatedTitle = `${label} ${(titlesWithNoDigits[label] || 0) + 1}`;
    
       return {
        ...obj,
        [next.id]: updatedTitle,
      };
}, {});
```

The response I am looking for is:

```
{
        z1: 'Oranges 1',
        y1: 'Apples 1',
        // Oranges 2 deleted
        a1: 'Oranges 2',
        b1: 'Apples 2',
        // Apples 3 deleted
        a3: 'Apples 3',
        b2: 'Oranges 3',
        b6: 'Apples 4',
        c3: 'Oranges 4',
        x1: 'Apples 5',
}
```

I am trying javascript `reduce` function. Can anyone give an idea, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the count in an object mapping it with the title

```js
const req = [
  { id: "z1", title: "Oranges 1" },
  { id: "y1", title: "Apples 1" },
  // Oranges 2 deleted
  { id: "a1", title: "Oranges 3" },
  { id: "b1", title: "Apples 2" },
  // Apples 3 deleted
  { id: "a3", title: "Apples 4" },
  { id: "b2", title: "Oranges 4" },
  { id: "b6", title: "Apples 5" },
  { id: "c3", title: "Oranges 5" },
  { id: "x1", title: "Apples 6" },
];

const labels = {};

const reg = /[a-zA-z]+/;
const response = req.reduce((obj, next) => {
  let title = "";
  const label = next.title;

  title = label.match(reg)?.[0] || "";

  if (title) {
    if (labels[title]) {
      labels[title] = labels[title] + 1;
    } else {
      labels[title] = 1;
    }
  }

  return {
    ...obj,
    [next.id]: `${title} ${labels[title]}`,
  };
}, {});

console.log(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a counter for each fruit when updating the titles. First declare a `Map` (or object) to keep the count for each fruit. Then we use `map` on the `req` object to generate each new object in the array while updating the counter for each fruit.

```js
const req = [
    {id: 'z1', title:"Oranges 1"},
    {id: 'y1', title:"Apples 1"},
    // Oranges 2 deleted
    {id: 'a1', title: "Oranges 3"},
    {id: 'b1', title: "Apples 2"},
    // Apples 3 deleted
    {id: 'a3', title: "Apples 4"},
    {id: 'b2', title: "Oranges 4"},
    {id: 'b6', title: "Apples 5"},
    {id: 'c3', title: "Oranges 5"},
    {id: 'x1', title: "Apples 6"},
];

// maps fruits to the number of occurrences
let fruitCounters = new Map();

const res = req.map(tab => {
    // remove number from title
    let bareTitle = tab.title.split(' ')[0];
    // update counter (initialize with 0 if key missing)
    fruitCounters[bareTitle] = (fruitCounters[bareTitle] ?? 0) + 1;
    // put together the updated title string
    const updatedTitle = `${bareTitle} ${fruitCounters[bareTitle]}`;
    return {
        id: tab.id,
        title: updatedTitle,
    }
});

console.log(res)
```